# Notepad++ RegEx replace with Zerofill

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace a list like this:

```
105164 25
105164 26
105164 29
105496 1
105496 2
```

To

```
105164_0025
105164_0026
105164_0029
105496_0001
105496_0002
```

Something like `(\w)([0-9]+)` to `_$1` but how to do the left zero padding?

Comment: A single regex can't do that. Perhaps Notepad++ has an option to right-justify columns? Then you could use a regex to pad the numbers with zeroes instead of spaces.

Comment: you are talking about a irregular language, which cannot be expressed by regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ ]([0-9]+) to _$1   --do your first replace
_([0-9])$ to _000$1
_([0-9][0-9])$ to _00$1
_([0-9][0-9][0-9])$ to _0$1
```

Kind of a cheat method but that's the only way I can think of.

Comment: Nice edit. I would use a " " without square brackets but it makes it more readable here on stack overflow.

Comment: _([0-9])$ to `_000$1` (underscore)

Comment: Fixed. Also you can do this with just 3 replaces by combining them really. Also I wonder if its possible using OR (|)

Answer (score 5):

You can do in two passes:

**first pass:**
Find what: `(\d+)$`
Replace with: `_0000$1`

**second pass:**
Find what: `_0*(\d{4})$`
Replace with: `_$1`