# find certain number digit and add character in notepad++

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I am trying to use Notepad++ to find number sets that has wrong digit and add zero in front of it to fix the issue.

So, I need to find number higher than 2 digit and lower than 6 digit. Then add zero to make it 6 digit.

This must be done in notepad++ or batch since others without computational background also need to run it.

I tried to study some regex but could not come up with a good way to fill up to 6 digit.

Here is some example that I need to do automatically:

```
1   1   21  10121   416138
1   1   22  10122   574158
1   1   23  10123   43218
1   1   24  10124   58157
1   1   25  10125   5880
1   1   26  10126   127144
```

to

```
1   1   21  010121  416138
1   1   22  010122  574158
1   1   23  010123  043218
1   1   24  010124  058157
1   1   25  010125  005880
1   1   26  010126  127144
```

Comment: Is this a tab delimited file or a fixed fielded file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ RegEx replace with Zerofill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624498/notepad-regex-replace-with-zerofill)

Answer (score 0):

Not a really nice way to do it, but works <del>for smaller amounts of number sets</del>. I tested with 2150 lines of your example and it is almost instantly done. Starts struggling at around 1 million lines though. It works but takes its time:

Using Search and Replace in Notepad++ with search-mode regular expressions search for

`\b([0-9]{3,5})\b`

and replace with `0\1`

and hit `Replace all` 3 times.
So every 3-5 digit number will be replaced by itself with a 0 in front of it. When replacing all 3 times you are making sure that even 3 digit numbers are filled up with 3 leading zeroes.

Again not a nice way, but worked for me...

<del>EDIT: Just saw it has to be done automatically... Maybe notepad++ has some tools to execute search and replace as a script, but I will leave that up to others ;)</del>

Yet another EDIT: I just could not help myself I had to find it out... I used the macro function of notepad++ to record the process of the above explained S&R and looked up where you can find you saved macros...

Outcome was this:

```
<Macro Key="32" Shift="yes" Alt="yes" Ctrl="no" name="MyUpdater">
  <Action sParam="" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1700" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="\b([0-9]{3,5})\b" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1601" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="2" wParam="0" message="1625" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="0\1" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1602" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="768" wParam="0" message="1702" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="1609" wParam="0" message="1701" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1700" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="\b([0-9]{3,5})\b" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1601" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="2" wParam="0" message="1625" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="0\1" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1602" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="768" wParam="0" message="1702" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="1609" wParam="0" message="1701" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1700" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="\b([0-9]{3,5})\b" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1601" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="2" wParam="0" message="1625" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="0\1" lParam="0" wParam="0" message="1602" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="768" wParam="0" message="1702" type="3"/>
  <Action sParam="" lParam="1609" wParam="0" message="1701" type="3"/>
</Macro>
```

Close Notepad++.
Go to `%appdata%\Notepad++\` and open the file `shortcuts.xml` **with the normal texteditor** (notepad++ will overwrite it back to normal state) and place the xml code from above in there (there should already be a macro in there named "Trim Trailing and Save"; just put it under the closing `</Macro>` tag and save it. When you open Notepadd++ now and click on Macro in the Menubar there should be one called "MyUpdater".
Currently the shortcut is set to  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Space</kbd>  but you can change it clicking on Macro -> Edit Shortcut.

This worked for me and like this you can "export" the makro to other users.

To reverse this operation you can Search for `\b([0])` and replace it with an empty string. Notice that you have to check Regular Expressions again! Here it is enough to hit Replace all once.

If there is anything left feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40601412.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-5" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET /a column4=1000000+%%d
 SET /a column5=1000000+%%e
 ECHO %%a %%b %%c !column4:~-6! !column5:~-6!
 )
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40601412.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

read the file and tokenise as token1..token5 to %%a..%%e

Add 1000000 to each of the last 2 columns which will produce a number 1000000..1999999 in each.

`Echo` the five columns out again, %%a..%%c as they stand, and the last 6 characters of each of `column5` and `column6`

The spacing is up to you. Since the fields are all fixed-length (1,1,2,6,6) then use spaces or tabs as required in the `echo` line.

If column3 may be 1 or 2-digit, then

```
 SET /a column3=1000000+%%c
```

is required, and *echo* `!column3:~-2!` in place of `%%c`.